# AutoHotKey code to receive ctrl+x while pressing ctrl+c twice

Tags: autohotkey

AutoHotKey code to receive <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> while pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> twice

Can anyone help with this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please try describing your problem a little more clearly?

Comment: ok. The thing is that I'm using my mouse's additional buttons as ctrlC and ctrlV. I'd like to use ctrlC assigned button as ctrlX if I press the button twice.

Comment: ctrlC or ctrlV? title and answer and comments say different things

Comment: damn! The title is wrong. Of course, I meant the ctrlC combination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, not <kbd>V</kbd>, and assuming you want to keep the original <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> function but also use it for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> when pressing twice in a short time:

```
#persistent
Transform, cC, Chr, 3  ; store the value of ctrlC into cC.
hotkey, $^c, ctrlC, ON  ; this is basically the same as if to say $^c::..., but only deactivable
return

ctrlC:
    hotkey, $^c, ctrlC, OFF
    input, key, M L1 T0.2
    hotkey, $^c, ctrlC, ON

    if errorlevel = timeout
        send ^c
    else if key = %cC%
        send ^x
    else
        send %key%
return
```

should do..

also see [Input](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm) for further information. I used this little hotkey-command-trick in order to temporarily disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-Hotkey, because otherwise `input` would not recognize the second `c`

In this example, I set timeout to `0.2` seconds. Change it to your convenience.

About your capslock idea - sounds like a good idea to me, but anyways, we're not a code-provider network. The command `getKeyState` should help you started.

Comment: or maybe you could offer a code that works as follows: when I press caps lock, my ctrlC starts working as ctrlX. Thanks.

Comment: could you maybe specify, WHAT does not work? What is it that you want to achieve other than this?

Comment: ok, thing is that code only does ctrlC as it did without your code

Comment: what isn't working. "it does ctrlC" is not enough. It should work the following way: press `ctrl c` once, and after 0.2 seconds, it'll copy. press `ctrl c` once AND PRESS IT AGAIN WITHIN 0.2 SECONDS, and it'll send `ctrl x` instead..

Comment: my dear friend, it doesn't send ctrlX. Have you personally tried it?

Comment: Yes. You are probably not fast enough with pressing `ctrl c` twice in a row. As stated above, change the timer to a value which suits you.

Comment: You are seriously confusing me. ^^ -- anyways, glad it worked. Since you're new here, please don't forget to always mark the answer **accepted** which helped most in solving the problem, otherwise ppl will see your question as unanswered. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)